# Help with Wp + Mixitup code

Tags: categories

I'm using [MixItUp](http://mixitup.io/) and having this issue. I'm calling the filters like this:

```
<?php
$categories=  get_categories('child_of=14&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($categories as $category)
    echo '<li class="filter" data-filter="'.$category->category_nicename.'"><span>'.$category->cat_name.'</span></li>';
?>
```

it works fine, all categories are showing with their respective data filter, just as expected.

However, when I try to output the content for those categories, I get nothing at all, not even errors, just blank. This is the code I'm using:

```
<li class="mix <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) { echo $category->slug . ' ';} ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('prod_th'); ?>
</li>
```

Just in case, teh code works fine in pure HTML5, so I guess I'm doing something wrong in PHP or maybe forgetting something

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Thanx in advance :)

Fore reference, I'm using this: http://kune.fr/javascript/tutoriel-integreez-mixitup-a-wordpress/

Comment: Are there any error messages, especially with `WP_DEBUG` enabled? What does dumping `get_the_category()` give you?

Comment: no, nothing, in debug.log I only get this: [20-Dec-2013 23:46:41] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: website in mysite//wp-content/themes/mytheme/404.php on line 37 but I didn't work on 404.php yet, so it's OK